# Take Output From First Terraform and Use in Second Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need two different Terraform file for different purposes. In the Second Terraform file, I have to take input from the output of First Terraform file.

In my Scenario, My first Terraform creates an AWS Security Group. Now I have to use the the ID of this Security group in my Second Terraform file.

I also want to sure that Second Terraform creation cannot initilaize before First Terraform complete. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please post your code. You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask link for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many .tf files you are creating. Terraform first loads all the .tf files and then try to create a graph to create the resources. So you can do it like this.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "default" {
    name        = "allow_all"
    description = "Allow all inbound traffic"
    .
    .
}
```

Now you can use id of this security group in another file/other module. For ex. let's use it for ec2 creation. Like.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami = "${var.ami_id}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"

    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.default.id}"]
}
```

For more details about security group params, you can check following document.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html

Answer (score 0):

for this requirement you might want to use **terraform modules** with which you can have the luxury of code reuse as well as you can supply that ID of security group to as many terraform files as you want. And whenever you do terraform apply it will check for resource dependencies and execution will take place accordingly.